# Webpack HMR works in Node 5.x.x, but not in 6.x.x

Tags: node.js, webpack

So, I have a `webpack dev server` running which bundles and hot reloads my client side assets, along with proxying all requests to an express server running on a different port. This works perfectly, however, when I upgrade Node from `v.5.11.0` to `6.2.1`, I get this error in the terminal:

```
Error: Cannot GET /dist/bundle.js
at raiseUrlNotFoundError (/Users/OSX/WebstormProjects/wittiest/node_modules/loopback/server/middleware/url-not-found.js:15:17)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/OSX/WebstormProjects/wittiest/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/Users/OSX/WebstormProjects/wittiest/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
at /Users/OSX/WebstormProjects/wittiest/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
at Function.process_params (/Users/OSX/WebstormProjects/wittiest/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/Users/OSX/WebstormProjects/wittiest/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
at SendStream.error (/Users/OSX/WebstormProjects/wittiest/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:120:7)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at SendStream.emit (events.js:188:7)
at SendStream.error (/Users/OSX/WebstormProjects/wittiest/node_modules/serve-static/node_modules/send/index.js:245:17)
```

Any ideas?